# Android marquee text is resetting if another TextView's text is changed

Tags: android, textview, marquee

TextView marquee resets when another text is changed. Well, if the marquee text contains Japanese, it doesn't reset. But if it contains only English, then it gets reset whenever another textview's text is changed.

Here's the xml code.

```
    <app.farhanfarooqui.vocaplayer.ScrollingTextView
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:id="@+id/songTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/skipBackward"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Song's Title"
        android:textColor="#ccbbb4"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
```

This problem is only occurring on devices running on android versions lower than lollipop

Comment: Try to place this inside of a fragment and see how it goes

Comment: Any other way except that?? My code works as expected for both Japanese and English on Lollipop, but not on Jelly Bean

Comment: That's all that I can think of, if you keep if separate from the display application you can at least have consistency through the versions. And it should take care of the issue without compromising the performance, look, etc